# Ancient Greek Mathematical Notation

Tags: notation, arithmetic, math-history, number-systems

[image: Greek Mathematical Notation]

While reading the [CMU FLAC overview](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eflac/pdf/lect-01.pdf), I stumbled upon the above image. While I have seen Greek numerals before, I had no idea that there was an entire algebraic symbology developed in Greek (though this isn't too surprising). To try and find more about this particular notation, I reverse Google Image searched it and found nothing (well, I was greeted to snippets written in the Tengwar, but that's besides the point).

What is this notation? Can you direct me to an overview of the system?

Comment: There's a  math history stackexchange. Perhaps ask there instead of here.

Comment: I'm skeptical also, both by looking at the (non)repeated symbols, and also because the "translated" expression is extremely unlikely as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Diophantus. See Heath's explanation of this notation in  https://archive.org/details/diophantusofalex00heatiala/page/38/mode/2up?view=theater